# Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

Tags: php

I want to create a system with license with my own code,but gives me an error

the code is like this and in lic.txt is the same 1234567,what is wrong?

This is the error,if i put @ in front of fread dosent show the error but does not open the file

> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /home/u422978792/public_html/platforma/license/index.php on line 7
>       Invalid license key

```
        <?php



    $fp = fopen("http://platforma.dar-project.org/license/lic.txt", "r");
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 10);
    $license = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
    fclose($fp);

    if ($license == "1234567") {

    echo "Your license key is valid";

    } else {

    die("Invalid license key");
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: where is $filename ?

Comment: Have you thought this through? Everyone who accesses this PHP script will see "Your license key is valid"

Comment: You don't appear to have set $filename it needs to be an integer higher than 0. Pretty much what the error says....

Comment: you use filesize($filename) but maybe you want to use $fp

Comment: `@` only suppresses error messages.

Answer (score 9):

You need to check file size `if(filesize($my_file) > 0)` before use `fread`.

For example:

```
<?php

$my_file = 'list.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r');
$data = '';
if(filesize($my_file) > 0)
    $data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
//---
echo $data;
//---
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP will return warnings and/or errors if the file doesn't exist (maybe it's mis-spelled or a malformed URL) or if the file-size is 0 bytes.

Here is a small function that verifies and returns either the file content in a string, or will return a "-1", in which case you know there was a problem while reading.

```
$file_content = ReadtextFile( "file.txt" ); // caller


function ReadtextFile($FileName)
  {
  if (file_exists($FileName) )
    {
    $file_size = filesize($FileName);
    if ($file_size == 0) return "";
    }
  else return "-1";

  if (!$fp = fopen($FileName, "r")) return "-1";

  $s01 = fread($fp, filesize($FileName));
  fclose($fp);

  return $s01;
  }
```

Comment: Could you at least format your code properly? And why don't you use `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I find this format correct. Been programming for over 30 years. Sorry you didn't find it useful.

Comment: You're welcome to work with this formatting, but for current PHP programming, it's recommended to work with speaking variables and formatting like [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). This makes code much more readable

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason behind the

> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

your file `lic.txt` should be empty. Therefore, `fread()` can not  read anything from the file.

and hence your condition leads to echo 'Invalid license key'.

Answer (score 0):

`$filename` is undefined. Do this:

`$filename = "lic.txt";`

Don't forget to append the url. I suggest you do it as a different variable.

Comment: There also seems to be a problem in the `filesize` function

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion ,I have come across this problem when runing a opencart website,
my solution is increasing the  size of disk for the domain. OR Delete unnecessary items from your file manager of your Cpanel of your domain.

hope will help

Answer (score 0):

PHP will return warnings and/or errors if the file doesn't exist this is a code.

```
<?php
if(file_exists("webdictionary.txt"))
{
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or 
die("Unable to open file!");
$len =filesize("webdictionary.txt");
echo "File content lenths:- $len .<br>";
echo "file containt.<br>";
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
echo fgetc($myfile);
}
echo "<br>";
fclose($myfile);
echo "$myfile";
}
else 
{
return -1;  
}

?>
```